# What is the Google API URL to user data?

Tags: url, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, access-token

After authenticating with OAuth2 and get the access token, the next step is get Google API URL to user data.

The Facebook API URL to user data is basically https://graph.facebook.com/me/ or [https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser-id%7D/) depending on the case.

On Google+ what is the URL?

I need to get data as the user name, profile photo ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new [people.get()](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) with `userID=me`. Make sure you have sufficient oauth scope to do so.